# Hide navigation bar COMPLETELY (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, keyboard

There are many videos about hiding navigation bar by using setSystemUiVisibility or something like this. However, navigation bar is being showed again after using keyboard to write username or password. And probably that solution will be broken because of other things. Help me to hide navigation bar completely like in the games. My app just don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

In your res/values/styles.xml file copy this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Here the parent theme is the theme you are currently using. Typically it will be in the file like this as default:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then go to the AndroidManifest.xml and make it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.name">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity
                   android:theme="Apptheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

What you do here is change your activity's theme to Apptheme.NoActioBar theme.

Then run your app and you will have no action bar.

Comment: Are you seriously? I asked how to hide navigation bar and you are explaining the way to hide action bar???